# How to add commands to be run after a systemd-controlled system service?

Tags: scripts, battery, systemd

I made a service [following this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux) so I did:
Created a systemd service unit
Created a startup shell script
Configured and installed the service

Now, my script is [this one](https://github.com/cirelli94/first-boot/blob/master/battery-script.sh). Basically, at startup it did something depending if my laptop is charging or not, and then every X minutes it check it again and set CPUs frequencies etc..

Now, sometimes it happens I want to stop it to reobtain full power by my laptop, so I stop it, but I now should set again CPUs frequencies etc.
Is it possible that, when I do `systemctl stop battery-script.service` it execute another script or some lines of code before stopping?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `ExecStop`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846289/systemd-how-to-use-execstoppre-in-service-files

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) I have to use `ExecStop=` in my battery-script.service.
Now it looks like:

```
[Unit]


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/battery.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/battery-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```